# ¿Cómo puedo crear una función en Python que me compare y me reemplace algunos valores en listas?

Tags: python, lista

Intento crear una función que tome 3 listas y analice sus elementos y compare los que están en las mismas posiciones y me determine si la diferencia entre los 3 elementos es mayor a determinada tolerancia y si la diferencia no es mayor a la tolerancia, esta función iguala todos los elementos de la posición al número menor que se encuentre en esa posición, tengo algo así (pero no funciona):

```
def son_similares(valor1, valor2, tolerancia=1e-6):
    return abs(valor1 - valor2) <= tolerancia

def reemplazar_similares(*listas, tolerancia=1e-6):
    # Filtrar listas no vacías
    listas_no_vacias = [lista for lista in listas if len(lista) > 0]

    # Verificar si hay al menos dos listas no vacías para la comparación
    if len(listas_no_vacias) < 2:
        return "No hay suficientes listas con datos para comparar."

    # Iterar sobre los elementos de las listas
    for elementos in zip(*listas_no_vacias):
        # Obtener el valor de referencia (primer elemento no vacío)
        valor_referencia = next(elemento for elemento in elementos if elemento is not None)
        
        # Verificar si todos los elementos son similares
        if all(son_similares(valor, valor_referencia, tolerancia=tolerancia) for valor in elementos):
            # Reemplazar todos los elementos por el valor de referencia
            for lista in listas_no_vacias:
                for i, valor in enumerate(elementos):
                    lista[i] = valor_referencia
```

Comment: y que quiere decir no funciona??? tira un error??? no hace lo que queres?? lo hace mal??? anda en algunos casos??

Comment: No hace lo que quiero y tampoco corre

Comment: bueno.. si no corre, ahi esta tu primer problema.. y que error recibis?? porque si no corre, algun error tira...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta al final de la función reemplazar_similares, en el ciclo que usas para modificar las listas. El indice de los items a modificar te lo da la iteracion sobre zip, no `elementos`:

```
def reemplazar_similares(*listas, tolerancia=1e-6):
    # Filtrar listas no vacías
    listas_no_vacias = [lista for lista in listas if len(lista) > 0]

    # Verificar si hay al menos dos listas no vacías para la comparación
    if len(listas_no_vacias) < 2:
        return "No hay suficientes listas con datos para comparar."

    # Iterar sobre los elementos de las listas
    for i, elementos in enumerate(zip(*listas_no_vacias)):
        # Obtener el valor de referencia (primer elemento no vacío)
        valor_referencia = next(elemento for elemento in elementos if elemento is not None)
        # Verificar si todos los elementos son similares
        if all(son_similares(valor, valor_referencia, tolerancia=tolerancia) for valor in elementos):
            # Reemplazar todos los elementos por el valor de referencia
            for lista in listas_no_vacias:
                lista[i] = valor_referencia
```

Ten en cuenta que si quieres que se sustituyan por el valor mínimo deberías usar `min` y no `next` (que te da el primer valor no nulo, el de la primera lista con valor no nulo en esa posición).